# Select over multiple tables with different fields

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Lets say I want to code a search engine for a website which has different tables (users, posts, articles, products), and create a generic search for all them.
Rather than how to do it I would like to know if it makes sense to do this in a single query, being a site with really low traffic.
Is there any pros am I missing besides any performance gain, or it would be the same if I run a query for each table?

Answer (score 0):

This is very subjective question, and you will soon get some feedback to revise it as Stackoverflow is not a discussion area. Anyways,

My view is that join query or single query has no relevance here. A user can be join by post. But in search you want to list a user even if he has not written post. Also, the fields of User are different from product and different from post. So, why combine them, when their display is different?

Even if you want to fire a single query you can use `union` between queries, but imagine a front end. For user you probably want to show their avatar with name and public thing, for product again you will show their image and price, and for post you might go with google like result, all are in different grid/area of page.

Better option is you use ajax and search them separately and show them in separate boxes on your result page. like google ads or this site shows.